# Microservices communication over Kafka

Tags: asynchronous, apache-kafka, microservices

I have 4 services and I need to implement the communication from each other using asynchronous messages over Kafka, but I have doubts about how many topics to do this.

I need to implement the SAGA pattern with this 4 services.

**Update 1**

The communication between services is to perform Events/Choreography.  Something like describe in this [article](https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/) . But I'm not so sure if it is a request/response communication.

Need I two topics per service, one to requests and another for responses, each one with their own schema?

Is it ok to use just two topics over all, one to publish the saga request and another to participants publish the results of their local execution?

Or any other pattern?

Any insights?

Comment: is it a request response communication? What is type of communication does these services need. This help answer better. Please clarify.

Comment: Refer to Martin Kleppmann's blog entry https://martin.kleppmann.com/2018/01/18/event-types-in-kafka-topic.html

Comment: @Saptarshi, I will read this blog entry! Thank you!